# Angular 4 when I click forgot password link from email it redirect to login?

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm doing forgot password in Angular when I received email and click it or copy paste it in browser it redirects to the login page with no reason with the both ways single and child case.

```
  // { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
// { path: 'reset/:token', component: ResetPasswordComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'guest',
    component: GuestComponent,
    canActivateChild: [GuestGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      // {
      //   path: 'forgot',
      //   component: ForgotPassComponent,
      // },
      {
        path: 'forgot/:token',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
```

Guest component HTML has: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
When put link beside forgot password link it works, but it's not working from email.
Anyone has idea about it?
`GuestGuardService` only see if it is login doing logout.

Comment: Can you share the link you are using in the email?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/guest/forgot/8346c17ad858a1b8a76cc10efb97cc1a75e78127cca9402163d2da50715757d0

Comment: anyone? pls help

Comment: In your GuardService or on ResetPasswordCmponent are you redirecting to login on any specific condition? Just recheck those conditions.

Comment: How did you solve that at the end? I'm trying to implement a similar thing..

Comment: you might have some check if not login then redirect in app component

Comment: i removed internal redirection in component